# looking up results in another table and printing out on webpage

Tags: php, mysql

I print out on web page the user and avatar with the following
 code but wish to also add the users balance to the output
 which is in another table.. both tables share user although
 in the balance table there are users that are not registered
 in the user info table

Table userinfo

```
              user                  |        avatar        |

 ------------------------------------------------------------

 29758b15-e021-4b3b-aad7-088b3843a9f6|     Neido Toxx       |

 313b96f2-b9f1-4c8b-a3d0-5997d9a7bc1c|     Marla Abbot      |

 98fde03e-377b-4b51-8ad6-6fb492e75298|     Captian Grid     |
```

Table balances

```
              user                  |        balance        |

 ------------------------------------------------------------

 29758b15-e021-4b3b-aad7-088b3843a9f6|         1000         |

 313b96f2-b9f1-4c8b-a3d0-5997d9a7bc1c|            0         |

 98fde03e-377b-4b51-8ad6-6fb492e75298|         2500         |

 abcde03e-377b-4b51-8ad6-6fb492e75298|            0         |





$result = mysql_query("SELECT user,avatar FROM userinfo");
if (!$result) {
die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}
$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);
echo "<table><tr >";
// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
    echo " <td>{$field->name}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td>$cell</font></td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select balance.user, info.avatar, balance.balance 
from user_balance balance
left join user_info info on info.user = balance.user
```

Comment: TY for your reply..when i insert your code into mine for the select and adjusting it to reflect the table is balances.balance  I get the following error User Info Table
Query to show fields from table failed  User Info Table
Query to show fields from table failed

Comment: I think you have to change your code. Use mysql_fetch_assoc($query) to retrieve array of associated arrays. So it wouldn't be necessary to retrieve fields. You will have to use simple foreach like: 

    foreach($users as $user){
        echo $user['user'];
        echo $user['avatar'];
        echo $user['balance'];
    }

Comment: Table Query to show fields from table failed  .... is the error I get on the webpage